# Derive probability mass function from probability-generating function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given the probability generating function

$$G(z) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{3+z}{3-z}$$,

how can one derive the pmf?

I know that I have the manipulate the function into a series:

$$G(z) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}p(x)z^x$$

I tried using the geometric series and got:

$$G(z) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}3^{-x}(\frac{z}{6} + 0.5)z^x$$

but now I am stuck because I can not get rid of that z/6 term.

Comment: Don't forget to put your punctuation inside the double dollars, otherwise they format by themselves on the following line.

Comment: You have $G(z) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}p(x)z^x$ so consider what the derivatives of $G$ are. Perhaps there is some relation between $p(n)$ and $G^{(n)}(0)$.

Comment: $$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}3^{-x}\frac{z}{6}z^x=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac163^{-x}z^{x+1}=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac123^{-x-1}z^{x+1}=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac123^{-x}z^{x}$$

Answer (score 2):

You have to find the Taylor series expansion of your function

$$G(z) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{3+z}{3-z}=\frac{1}{2} \frac{6+z-3}{3-z}= \frac{3}{3-z}-\frac12=\frac{1}{1-z/3}-\frac12$$

Now,

$$\frac{1}{1-t}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^n$$

Hence

$$G(z)=-\frac12+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n}z^n$$

$$G(z)=\frac12+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n}z^n$$

The probability of $n>0$ is thus

$$p_n=\frac{1}{3^n}$$

And $p_0=\frac12$.